# Select closest rows by XOR distance metric at the field

Tags: surrealdb

Let's say I have a `Contacts` table with an `id` field which is binary data.

I need to select `N` rows whose XOR distance is closest to some value in the query.

What is the best way to do that in SurrealDB?

Comment: What code do you have? (Add it to your question, this isn't a code writing service. If you don't have code, make an effort.) What's an XOR distance? (I don't know surrealdb so maybe it's specific to that and I just don't know?)